# Possible typo in Numerical linear algebra by Trefethen and Bau (3rd ed).

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

On page 29 (at the bottom), they say:
[image]

But the 2-norm of a vector has a square root in it, so on the RHS of the >= sign, there should be a square root sign, no? I would have thought that the reasoning here is that when taking the 2-norm, the result must be greater than or equal to contribution from just the first-element to the 2-norm (which is $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + w^*w}$), i.e. what the 2-norm would be if you zero-ed out everything except the first element of the vector. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a typo here. Note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 & w^* \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 \\
w
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 + w^*w \\
Bw
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Therefore,
$$\left|\left| \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 + w^*w \\
Bw
\end{bmatrix}\right|\right|_2 = \sqrt{(\sigma_1^2 + w*w)^2 + (Bw)_1^2 + \cdots+(Bw)_{n-1}^2}\ge \sigma_1^2 + w^*w.
$$
(Assuming $w\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$). I think maybe you were just forgetting that, in the definition of the two norm, each component of the vector is squared and then summed before taking the square root.

Comment: Yes, I see I forgot this detail. Thank you!